# Match a list of shapefile names to list of raster names then do something

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, rasterio, fiona

I have a list of shapefiles and a list of rasters that I would like to match the names then do some data extraction for later analysis. The beginning of each raster and shapefile begins with "yyyy-mm-dd_UNL_Wheat_NIN" and I would like to use this as the match criteria. I have the code below to show what I would like to do. Right now I only have it able to iterate over a list of orthos with one shapefile. How would I make it so there is a conditional loop prior to do something loop?

```
shape_path = glob.glob('/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Shapefiles/'+'*.shp')

/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Shapefiles/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN.shp
/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Shapefiles/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN.shp

raster_path = glob.glob('/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/'+'*.tif')

/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 1.tif
/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 2.tif
/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 1.tif
/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 2.tif
```

Here is what I would like to loop through and extract to an array for the shapefile that matches the raster.

```
# Iterate through ortho names
for ortho in ortho_path:
    # Print name as a check
    print(ortho)

    with rasterio.open(ortho) as img:
        # Code to automatically find date in yyyy-mm-dd in file name
        match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', img.name)
        img_date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        # assign location name
        #img_loc = img.name.split("/")
        img_loc = ""
        # Get features and barcode name from shape file
        for feature in shape:
            shape_cord = [feature["geometry"]]
            barcode = feature["properties"]['Barcode']
            out_image, out_transform = mask(img, shape_cord, crop=True)
            GLI = (2*np.mean(out_image[1,:,:]) - np.mean(out_image[0,:,:]) - np.mean(out_image[2,:,:]))/(
                2*np.mean(out_image[1,:,:]) + np.mean(out_image[0,:,:]) + np.mean(out_image[2,:,:]))

            # Appending values to array
            flightdate.append(img_date)
            flightloc.append(img_loc)
            brcd.append(barcode)
            gli.append(GLI)
```

Comment: It's best practice to avoid leading numerals in names of both rasters and vector datasets, since table names in many GIS applications require a leading alpha. Since you have the opportunity to name them here, adding a leading 'y' or other alphabetic character would be wise.

Answer (score 0):

I like [collections.defaultdict(list)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for grouping:

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
import os

shapelist = ['/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Shapefiles/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN.shp',
             '/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Shapefiles/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN.shp']

rasterlist = ['/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 1.tif',
              '/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 2.tif',
              '/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 1.tif',
              '/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 2.tif']
d = dd(list)
for shape in shapelist:
    match = os.path.basename(shape).split('.')[0] #basename to get filename, and split '.' [0] to get for example 2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN
    for raster in rasterlist:
        if match in raster:
            d[shape].append(raster)

for s, v in d.items():
    print(s, v) #A dictionary with the shapefile as key and a list of raster(s) as value
    #/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Shapefiles/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN.shp ['/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 1.tif', '/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-05_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 2.tif']
    #/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Shapefiles/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN.shp ['/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 1.tif', '/Volumes/ML - External/2017-2018 season/Orthos/2018-05-09_UNL_Wheat_NIN_Flight 2.tif']

for shape, rasters in d.items():
    #do something
```